# Hi! how to put the div background image place side by side with the <ul> BUT with NO using FLOAT. Just with the width of every elements

Tags: html, css

I can't understand why the div's child of container (DIV logo and DIV meny )doesn't stay inside the div container;
I put width:100% on div container and the  goes down and not in-line with the background image. I don't know if background-image has particular properties.

As the title i don't wanna use FLOAT with position:float because i wanna understand what i mess up.
PS. with position:float evertything goes right.

I'm sorry for the mess in this post, but it is my first answer on stackoverflow. Understand me please :)

```
    <!doctype>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <style>
        
            *{ box-sizing: border-box;
                font-family: sans-serif;
    
            }
           


            body{
                
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                
            }


             
                #container {
              
                    
                width: 100%;
                background-color: cornflowerblue;
                height: 300px;
                
                
                
            }
            

            
             #container #logo{
                
                background-image: url(progetto-2020-2021/logo-nero.png);
                width: 10%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: blue;
                display: block;
            }
            
            #container #menu {
                
                width 70%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: aqua;
                
            }
            
    
        </style> 

        
        
        
    </head>
    <body>

       
        <div id="container"> 
        
   



<div id="logo">             
        <a></a>
        </div>
                

        

<div id="menu"> 
                <ul>
                    <li>ciao</li>
                    <li>mamma</li>
                    <li>papa</li>
                    <li>nonna</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        
        </div>
    
      

    

</body> 
    
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting display: inline-block to both child div elements.
By default all div elements will display as a block, thus you cannot control their size with the width rule.
Once you change the display rule to inline-block, you can control their widths correctly.